# Why will the activity not go to next activity on Button click when correct username and password are entered? Android Studio- sqlite

Tags: android

I know the data is correctly entered in the login section because when i try to register the same username and password , it tells me that this is already taken. So the database part is working correctly. At click on the sign in button(After the correct user nd password is entered) , nothing happens. It just stays there, and doesnt go to the next activity.

[sign_in_activity image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/izK7P.png)

What could be the problem here? I just dont see what went wrong. 
Note: the "sign in button" is declared as "hom_main(View v);"  " register button" is "fac_Reg(View v);" and the "Admin? Button" is declared as "register(View v);"

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
public EditText fcode;
public EditText fpass;
public static String fccode;
public String fcpass;
DatabaseAdapter db;
Cursor c;
/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    fcode=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.Username);
    fpass=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.Password);

}
public void fac_reg(View v)
{
    startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this, register.class));
}

public void register(View v)
{
    startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this, admin.class));
}
public void hom_main(View v)
{
  db = new DatabaseAdapter(this);
    fccode=fcode.getText().toString();
    fcpass=fpass.getText().toString();
    if(fccode.equals("")||fcpass.equals(""))
    {
        if(fccode.equals(""))
        {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Pls Fill in the   
 Username!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
        else  if(fcpass.equals(""))
        {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Pls Fill in the 
 Password!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    }
    else
    {
        try{

            db.open();
            c=db.getRecordByName(fccode);
            if(c.getCount()==0)
            {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "No Teacher is 
 taking this course", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                return ;
            }
            if(!c.getString(2).equals(fcpass))
            {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Incorrect 

  Password!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                return ;
            }
            db.close();
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Could Not Retrieve 
 Data", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            return ;
        }
        startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this, Manage.class));;
        //Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Welcome "+fcname+" !", 
 Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
}

}
```

The names of onClick had been used in the class

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:paddingTop="125px"
>
<EditText
    android:id="@+id/Username"
    android:hint="Subject Code"
    android:layout_width="350px"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    >
    <requestFocus></requestFocus>
</EditText>
<EditText
    android:id="@+id/Password"
    android:password="true"
    android:paddingTop="20px"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:hint="Password"
    android:layout_width="350px"
    android:layout_gravity="center">
</EditText>
<Button
    android:id="@+id/signin"
    android:paddingTop="20px"
    android:text="Sign in"
    android:layout_width="150px"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:clickable="true"

    android:onClick="hom_main"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal" />

<Button
    style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="register "
    android:id="@+id/button3"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:onClick="fac_reg" />

<Button
    android:layout_width="146dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Admin?"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:id="@+id/b1"
    android:onClick="register" />
```

db.getRecordByname() code

```
 public Cursor getRecordByName(String code) throws SQLException
{

    Cursor mCursor =
            db.query(true, DATABASE_TABLE1, new String[] {
                            KEY_ROWID,
                            KEY_FACNAME,
                            KEY_PASSWORD,
                            KEY_CODE
                    },
                    KEY_CODE + "=" +"\""+ code+"\"",
                    null,
                    null,
                    null,
                    null,
                    null);
    if (mCursor != null) {
        mCursor.moveToFirst();
    }
    return mCursor;
}
```

Comment: Where is your Button OnClickListener..you have to implement OnClickListener first

Comment: As @VishalChauhan said, where is your onClickListener? Is it directly in the xml? Can you post your xml?

Comment: Can u post activity_main.xml?

Comment: please, share the code of db.getRecordByName(fccode) method.

Comment: where you are calling `hom_main(View v);`

Comment: It had been declared in the xml.. onClick

Comment: @PradeepGupta , i added the code that had been used to fetch the data for this activity.

Comment: you are getting the records from  db.getRecordByName(fccode) method?

Comment: yes ... the code should be entered in the this method. And then the cursor should search for it. But in this case, nothing seems to happen when signin button is clicked